# Set the select box to its default selected index using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, I have a select box

```
<select id="txtPriority" style="color:#008000;">
    <option value="0" style="color:#0000FF;">Low</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected" style="color:#008000;">Normal</option>
    <option value="2" style="color:#B22222;">Critical</option>
</select>
```

Now with that select box, I want to create a button **that when clicked** would return back the select box's selected item to the `<option>` that has `selected="selected"`. Now is this possible with a simple jQuery code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I well understood there's no need to use jQuery: just wrap that select in a form and use a reset button (see http://jsfiddle.net/vwqVJ/5/)

```
<form ...>
    <select id="txtPriority" style="color:#008000;">
    ...
    </select>

    <button type="reset">Restore choice</button>
</form>
```

In this way when you change the select you can always turn back to the initial state

If you need instead to use jQuery just invoke the reset method on the form element, like

```
$('form').get(0).reset()
```

otherwise, if you have no form at all (but you really should use it) just use

```
$('#txtPriority').val($('#txtPriority option[selected]').val())
```

Comment: this is nice but im not using any form tag somehow... i submit my data through jquery ajax

Comment: No form? Only with jQuery? So many wrong choice for so many reasons.

Comment: Straight jQuery: `$('#txtPriority').val($('#txtPriority option[selected]').val())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the meaning of 'a button that would return back the select box's selected item'
But

```
$("select#txtPriority option:selected").first();
```

Will give you selected option item.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#txtPriority').val('1');  //try this
```